# Was Donald Trump's father a member of the KKK?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, racism

[This tumblr post](http://nerdgasrnz.tumblr.com/post/151205630239/afroerotik-afroerotik-its-my-understanding) has garnered over 13,000 notes:

[image]

The post makes 3 main claims:

- Donald Trump's father was a member of the KKK for over 70 years
- He was arrested in 1927 at a KKK event
- He was photographed with his son and wife in 1999 wearing klan robes

What merit do these claims hold?

Comment: Ah ha! House of Cards inspiration.

Comment: Is it just me, or is the father's robe photoshopped terribly badly?

Comment: Yeah he's turned to an angle in the original but the robe is facing straight at the camera, so it doesn't match up with the head

Comment: I'd like to see information about the claim "he said he didn't know enough about the Klan to disavow them".

Comment: @Random832 It's a reference to [Trumps statement about David Duke and the KKK](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/fact-checker/wp/2016/03/01/donald-trump): "[Tapper:] there are these groups and individuals endorsing you. Would you just say unequivocally you condemn them [? ... Trump:] You wouldn’t want me to condemn a group that I know nothing about. [... Tapper:] The Ku Klux Klan? [Trump:] But you may have groups in there that are totally fine, and it would be very unfair. [Tapper:] Okay. I mean, I’m just talking about David Duke and the Ku Klux Klan here [Trump:] I don’t know any"

Comment: @Random832 To be fair, Trump said that he had a bad earpiece, and "Trump didn't know enough about the Klan to disavow them" is a particularily negative reading of the interview.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

> He was arrested in 1927 at a KKK event

This is true. He was arrested at the KKK riot for "refusing to disperse from a parade when ordered to do so", see for example [The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2016/02/28/in-1927-donald-trumps-father-was-arrested-after-a-klan-riot-in-queens/) or [Vice](http://www.vice.com/read/all-the-evidence-we-could-find-about-fred-trumps-alleged-involvement-with-the-kkk).

> He was photographed with his son in 1999 wearing klan robes

This is not true. The image is manipulated. See [snopes.com](http://www.snopes.com/donald-trumps-parents-kkk/) for more details, including the original image that it was based upon:

[image: Original image, according to Snopes]

> Donald Trump's father was a member of the KKK for over 70 years

There is no evidence for this claim one way or the other that I could find.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46268/discussion-on-answer-by-tim-was-donald-trumps-father-a-member-of-the-kkk).

Comment: Adding a comment because that's all I have rep for.  The FBI released the result of a name check of Fred Trump done back in the day:  https://vault.fbi.gov/fred-c.-trump/Fred%20C.%20Trump%20Part%2001%20of%2001/view.  Nothing incriminating, which isn't proof, but is decent evidence.